# Extreme slow after hibernate/ long suspend

Tags: 14.04, networking, suspend, hibernate, resume

I am on ubuntu 14 and installed it recently. I configured hibernate by creating a swap partition and can do hibernate. The problem is that after hibernate(prolonged suspend), laptop is very slow. The **login page stays frozen** for at least 5-10 minutes before I can enter password. After that I see that **wifi/networking is disabled**. It does not work until I restart network manager. Even after that system is very slow and takes around 20-30 minutes to become better but it never recovers fully.I have been searching for answers for more than 2 weeks but can not find proper lead.

I am adding [hibernate logs](https://jpst.it/Mban),[syslog](https://jpst.it/MbaK).Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am too having the same problem.

Comment: This problem still exists.

Comment: same issue on 18.04.  The computer is fine when I leave it, when I return after hibernation, it's dog slow.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I'm seeing the same problem with a brand new laptop with Ubuntu 20.04...